# Could you tell me diffrence sub and public sub?

Tags: vb.net, public

What is diffrences `Sub` and `public sub` on Vb.net ?
(I'm using Visual Studio 2012)
my teacher asked me and i searched google i just found difference between `Private Sub`, `Function` and `Class`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your teacher surely meant for you to actually **try** this yourself.  Easy to do, add a Class Library project to your test solution.  First thing you'll discover is that the Class or Module has to be declared Public explicitly to be usable from your main project.  For Sub and Function, VB.NET retains compatibility with previous VB versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Public` keyword is an access modifier. It states that every code that has a reference to the module or class where the sub is declared have access to it.
There are several access modifiers you can use in VB.Net - `Public`, `Friend`, `Protected`, `Protected Friend` or `Private`, each one indicates a different access level:

- `Public`: Available to everyone.
- `Friend`: Available only inside the current assembly.
- `Protected`: Available only to classes inheriting the current class.
- `Protected Friend`: Available only to inheritors or inside the current assembly. It's basically a combination of Protected and Friend.
- `Private`: Available only inside your Class or Module.

Of course, everything is available in the current Class or Module, regardless of it's access modifier.

You can read all about it in details in [the relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx#Access%20Modifiers).